# Google Sheet Script keeps appending blank columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following google sheet script that calls a URL to get data and populate the sheet with the data. The URL contains only two columns "Name" and "Username" but when I run the script for some reason it keeps adding 3 blank columns at the beginning of every record and it adds some sort of unique key column at the end for each record. The script is below, I cannot seem to figure out why it's doing this:

```
function populateSheetWithCSV(sheet, csvUrl, user, pw) {
  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl, {
    headers: {
      // use basic auth
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(
      user + ':' + pw, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8)
    }
  });
  var doc = XmlService.parse(resp);
  var users = doc.getRootElement().getAllContent();
  var spreadsheetContent = [];
  var maxLength = 0;
  var headerRow = ['Name', 'Username'];
  for (var j=0; j<users.length-1; j++)
  {
   var length = users[j].getValue().trim().split("\n").length;
   if (maxLength < length)
   {
     maxLength = length;
   }
  }
  // Get all the data into a 2D Array
  for (var i=0; i<users.length-1; i++)
  {
    var userDetails = users[i].getValue().trim().split("\n");
    if (userDetails.length > 1) {
      if (userDetails.length < maxLength)
      {
        var diff = maxLength - userDetails.length;
        for (var k = 0; k<diff; k++)
        {
          userDetails.unshift("");
        }
      }
      spreadsheetContent.push(userDetails);
    } 
  }
  Logger.log(spreadsheetContent);

// clear everything in the sheet
    sheet.clearContents().clearFormats();
// set headers
sheet.appendRow(headerRow);
// set the values in the sheet (as efficiently as we know how)
    sheet.getRange(
        2, 1,
        spreadsheetContent.length /* rows */,
        maxLength /* columns */).setValues(spreadsheetContent);
}
```

*** UPDATE ***

I've discovered the the URL I am fetching the data from returns the data in XML and looks like the following result below. Is there a way to modify the script to work with the XML data?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <Name>First Name 1</Name>
    <Username>user_name1</Username>
    <UniqueIdentifier>34644cba5-4090-4e3d646ba-222a6fe549fc</UniqueIdentifier>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Name>First Name 2</Name>
    <Username>user_name2</Username>
    <UniqueIdentifier>34644cba5-4090-4e3d646ba-222a6fe549fc</UniqueIdentifier>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the problem with CSV.

The minimal working fragment of the code (without your CSV) doesn't show the problem:

```
function populateSheetWithCSV_TEST() {

    var headerRow = ['Name', 'Username'];
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var spreadsheetContent = [['name1', 'user1'], ['name2', 'user2']];
    var maxLength = spreadsheetContent[0].length;

    // clear everything in the sheet
    sheet.clearContents().clearFormats();
    // set headers
    sheet.appendRow(headerRow);
    // set the values in the sheet (as efficiently as we know how)
    sheet.getRange(
        2, 1,
        spreadsheetContent.length /* rows */ ,
        maxLength /* columns */ ).setValues(spreadsheetContent);
}
```

Output:

[image]

---

**Update**

You can convert your XML into array this way:

```
function parse() {

  xml = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <NewDataSet>
    <Table>
      <Name>First Name 1</Name>
      <Username>user_name1</Username>
      <UniqueIdentifier>34644cba5-4090-4e3d646ba-222a6fe549fc</UniqueIdentifier>
    </Table>
    <Table>
      <Name>First Name 2</Name>
      <Username>user_name2</Username>
      <UniqueIdentifier>34644cba5-4090-4e3d646ba-222a6fe549fc</UniqueIdentifier>
    </Table>
  </NewDataSet>`

  const getValues = node => 
    ['Name','Username'].map(name => node.getChild(name).getText());
  
  const rows = XmlService.parse(xml).getRootElement()
    .getChildren('Table').map(getValues);

  Logger.log(rows); // out: [[First Name 1, user_name1], [First Name 2, user_name2]]

  /* old school
  var data   = XmlService.parse(xml);
  var tables = data.getRootElement().getChildren('Table');
  var rows   = [];
  for (table of tables) {
    var name = table.getChild('Name').getText();
    var username = table.getChild('Username').getText();
    rows.push([name, username])
  }  
  */

}
```

Bun I know next to nothing about XML parsing. Perhaps my solutions is not the best.

---

**Update 2**

You can add the array `rows` to the table about the same way as you did it in your script:

```
...
var spreadsheetContent = rows;

// clear everything in the sheet
sheet.clearContents().clearFormats();

// set headers
sheet.appendRow(headerRow);

// set the values in the sheet (as efficiently as we know how)
sheet.getRange( 
  2, 1,
  spreadsheetContent.length /* rows */,
  maxLength /* columns */).setValues(spreadsheetContent);
}
```

I haven't tested it. But if it worked already it should work now.

Comment: Thanks for that, i've just tried to call the URL with basic auth directly and discovered that the URL returns XML not CSV. I've updated my original question with an example return result. Is there a way to modify this script to allow the XML above? Thank you.

Comment: This is exactly why it makes sense to post a Minimal, Reproducible Example of the code whenever it's possible https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example This way, I'm sure, more than a half of problems would be solved even before posting. )

Comment: As for XML, I believe it's possible to parse the XML inside your script. Google has dedicated functions: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service

Comment: Thank you, your latest edit seems to work great but how do I loop through each data set and create a row of data on the spreadsheet?

Comment: This thread becomes too longish and unfocused. You better to post a next question. I'm sure you will get answer in no time. But you need be more detailed: how exactly you get the XML, why would it contain several 'DataSets' and what does it mean? I just showed you how to loop through one 'DataSet' (two row of the table in your samle)

Comment: I've made the second update. For the one 'DataSet'

Comment: Thank you, works great. One problem i'm having is if I have an address field in the getValues, I get an error saying: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getText' of null but the address isn't null. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably you need to change one line this way: `['Name', 'Username', 'Address'].map(name => node.getChild(name).getText());`. Probably. I don't see your new XML data, so it hard to tell.